# After saving my bitmap to a file the size is 0 KB

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a android app where I have a bitmap and I want to save it to the application data folder. The file is there after execution, but its 0kb and no picture is inside.

Where is the bug?

Here is my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

File f = new File(projDir + File.separator + newPath);
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Maybe IOException was raised?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but does `myBitmap.compress` return false? If so, you won't get anything in your stream.

Comment: any solution for this problem? only happening in one device android 5 for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `fo.flush()`

```
try {
   f.createNewFile();
   FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
   fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
   fo.flush()
   fo.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `fo.flush()`

```
try {
   f.createNewFile();
   FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
   fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
   fo.flush()
   fo.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit**

try this:

```
File f = new File(projDir + File.separator + newPath);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: This wouldn't help.  Streams are flushed prior to being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with FileOutputStream:

```
try {
  FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(projDir + File.separator + newPath);
  myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, fos);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call `createNewFile()` , it will be automatically created if it does not exist. I guess since you never delete it is already there and it is not created because of that.

Also as a good habit you should put clean up related code inside the `finally` block. This way if some error happens somewhere the file will be eventually closed.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
boolean success = myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
if(!success) {
     Log.w("myApp", "cannot compress image");
}
String patg = projDir + File.separator + newPath
File f = new File(projDir + File.separator + newPath);
Log.w("myApp", "cannot compress image");
try {
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if(fo != null) {
            fo.flush();
            fo.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```